# Is there any equivalent function of DATEPART(day, timestamp) in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have got a problem about extracting  'day' value from a date. SQL support date part for that but i want to extract it from pyspark. I have tried Date_format() function but i did not find specific letter for extracting day. like 'E' represents  day of week, there is no special key value in dateformat for extracting day value . How could i do that Kindly help me

kalyan

Answer (score 0):

Format letters:

- `D`- day of year
- `d` - day in month
- `u` - numeric day of week